# Standard diff format in SVN

Tags: svn, diff

Does a standard or normal diff format exist in SVN or only the unified format?

Comment: What do you call "standard diff format" ? As far as I know, there are several diff formats, (sed, unified, context) and none of them are standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`svn help diff` reveals this:

> --diff-cmd arg : use ARG as diff command

Therefore you should be able to use `svn diff --diff-cmd diff` to use the standard `diff`.

Comment: svn adds -u argument by default, (at least in version 1.5.1). So, you need to specify some diff arguments via -x to override unified format. E.g. "svn diff --diff-cmd diff -x -b" works for me

Answer (score 8):

svn diff --diff-cmd diff -x --normal

This has no side effects, unlike -b which causes changes in whitespace to be ignored.

Comment: Very cool. I did not know about the -x option. I've always made an external shell script with the diff command in it. Thanks!